Recover old website domain
I would need some support from someone who has an idea how I could get my domain(+website progress) back. 2y ago I stopped the payment for my website and after a while I found out that I need it.
If I go in the menu to check the purchases, I still have the history of buying the domain few years ago, but I cannot access it or recover anything from there.
I tried to search the old website adress, but it's not registered and I cannot either find it where the domain options are.
The website was http://kingwrapcustoms.co.uk
I would be very thankful if
Someone could help me with this matter.
Thank you.

Most hosts would have deleted everything long ago. If you're not paying for service, they will sell that server space to someone else. You should contact the host directly to ask.
You can try looking in the Internet Archive - if it indexed your content while the site was live, it would still have the content and you could start rebuilding from there.
